# Как в list запихнуть массив, но без объявления массива

Tags: c++, массивы, list, stl

`list<int mas[3]> l = {{1,2,3}};` не работает.

Comment: То есть вы хотите, чтобы список состоял из отдельных массивов по 3 элемента?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, верно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Более правильно было бы написать `list<int[3]>`, но это тоже не работает.

Используйте вместо обычного массива `std::array`:

```
std::list<std::array<int,3>> l = {{1,2,3}};
```